# SQL MAX Query Lookup from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some fun trying to return the `MAX` value from SQL Server :

```
SELECT 
    MAX(GPSdata_1.Longitude) AS Expr1, 
    MAX(GPSdata_1.Latitude) AS Expr2, 
    CAST(MAX(GPSdata_1.Speed) AS DECIMAL(9 , 0)) AS Expr3, 
    MAX(GPSdata_1.Date) AS Time, Units.FleetName 
FROM 
    GPSdata AS GPSdata_1 
INNER JOIN 
    Units ON GPSdata_1.UnitID = Units.IMEInumber 
GROUP BY 
    Units.FleetName
```

The issues for some reasons the Long and Lat are not returning the correct value

I have tried

```
select *
from mytable t1
inner join
  (
 select max(ID) 
from mytable
group by UnitID
) t2
 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Basically I have 1 table that has the ID in it and i want to return the last / Max record for the ID .

Comment: Can yo give so data examples? What do you have and what do you expect?

Comment: never mind i worked it out it end up working with FROM            GPSdata AS TT INNER JOIN
                             (SELECT        UnitID, MAX(Date) AS date1
                               FROM            GPSdata
                               GROUP BY UnitID) AS T2 ON TT.UnitID = T2.UnitID AND TT.Date = T2.date1 INNER JOIN
                         Units ON TT.UnitID = Units.IMEInumber
GROUP BY TT.Date, TT.Longitude, TT.Latitude, Units.FriendlyName, CAST(TT.Speed AS DECIMAL(9, 0))

Answer (score 0):

I end up getting it working with the following command

```
  SELECT TT.Longitude,TT.Latitude,TT.Date,CAST(TT.Speed AS DECIMAL(9, 0)) 
  AS Expr1,Units.FriendlyName
  FROM GPSdata AS TT 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT UnitID, MAX(Date) AS date1
              FROM GPSdata
              GROUP BY UnitID) AS T2 ON TT.UnitID = T2.UnitID 
                                     AND TT.Date = T2.date1 
  INNER JOIN Units ON TT.UnitID = Units.IMEInumber
  GROUP BY TT.Date,TT.Longitude,TT.Latitude,Units.FriendlyName,
  CAST(TT.Speed AS DECIMAL(9, 0))
```

Comment: Regarding your answer, how would someone be able the to find the solution with the information provided in your question?